# C#: Format Exception Was Unhandled when calling WriteLine

Tags: c#, string, format

I am currently working through the basic chapters of Pro C# 5.0 Textbook and I have copied the following code from the book

```
namespace BasicDataTypes {
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        NewingDataTypes();

    }



    static void NewingDataTypes() {
        Console.WriteLine("Using new to create variables");
        bool b = new bool();
        int i = new int();
        double d = new double();
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        Console.WriteLine("{0], {1}, {2}, {3}", b, i, d, dt);
        Console.ReadLine();     }
}
}
```

This is causing a runtime error when trying to parse the variables into a string. Am I missing something? The variables all have default values set.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What was the exceptions message and type?

Comment: I don't see any parsing here. On which line you get this error? And `{0]` should be `{0}`.

Comment: @SonerGönül I suspect he means "passing". (And I suspect that default initialises `DateTime`: depending on locale it may not be formattable.)

Comment: Sorry I meant the implicit parsing when converting the variables to string to be output. It happens on the call to WriteLine, cheers for quick responses.

Comment: @Richard Hmm, I didn't know that this would be change based on localization. I thought since `DateTime` struct imlements `IFormattable` interface, all `DateTime`'s can formattable. Interesting.

Comment: It's not just the DateTime variable causing this either, I have removed the variable from the WriteLine call (and the placeholder) and still get the exception being thrown..

Comment: @SonerGönül There are plenty of cases where `DateTime` values cannot be formatted, easiest is when the locale's calendar is not defined that far back. (But looking back, I think you have it with the `]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the first parameter of the line

```
Console.WriteLine("{0], {1}, {2}, {3}", b, i, d, dt);
```

Use a closing curly bracket instead of the square bracket.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", b, i, d, dt);
```

Hth

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!! a mix of being overly tired and no compile time errors in visual studio made me miss this typo. Sorry to waste everyones time. Is interesting it doesn't make a compiler error though.